# Using event to publish in multiple locales/languages

Tags: concrete5

I'm trying to hook into the publish page type event so that I can publish the same page in multiple language sites at the same time using page attributes to select which languages to use. The code below runs fine without errors, but instead of creating a page duplicate in the target language I just get a new page draft in the original language. What am I missing here?

Code

```
<?php

Events::addListener('on_page_type_publish',
function($event) {
    $page = $event->getPageObject();

    if ($page->getPageTypeHandle() == 'blog_entry') {

        $multilingualController = Core::make('\Concrete\Controller\Backend\Page\Multilingual');
        $multilingualController->setPageObject($page);

        $pageCollection = $page->getCollectionID();
        $pageSection = \Concrete\Core\Multilingual\Page\Section\Section::getBySectionOfSite($page);
        $pageLocaleText = $pageSection->getLanguageText();

        $targetLocale = \Concrete\Core\Multilingual\Page\Section\Section::getByLocale('nb_NO'); //Will be set from page attribute
        $targetLocaleCollection = $targetLocale->getCollectionID();

        $createNewData = array(
        'section' => $targetLocaleCollection,
        'cID' => $pageCollection
        );

        $action = $multilingualController->action('create_new', $createNewData);
        $theResult = $multilingualController->runAction($action, $createNewData);

    }
});
```